# Add dynamically xml tag to serialized object without modifying the object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an object serializable like this :

```
     [XmlRoot("MyObject")]
     [Serializable]
     public class MyObject
     {
        public MyObject()
        {       
        }

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }    
     }
```

Right now I am able to export this object in an xml file with the following code :

```
    public byte[] Export(MyObject myObject)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        byte[] value = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myObject);
            value = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

For the moment, my exported xml is like this :

```
        <MyObject Name="nameData">
```

I would like to export other data (a list of name related to myObject and obtained from another service) with this. But I cannot modify my MyObject class.

This is how I get the additionnal data :

```
public XElement GetExtraData(MyObject myObject)
{
            List<string> datas = service.GetData(myObject);
            var otherDatas = new XElement("otherDatas");
            foreach (var data in datas)
            {
                var dataElement = new XElement("data");
                var valueAttribute = new XAttribute("Value", data);
                dataElement.Add(valueAttribute);
            }
            otherDatas.Add(dataElement);
}
```

I would like to append this otherDatas element to my previous element in order to obtain the following :

```
<MyObject Name="nameData">
<data Value="valueData">
<data Value="valueData">
<data Value="valueData">
```

But I don't see how, as this new method returns me a xElement created by me, and the natively .net serialization returns me an array of bytes.

Comment: You could make a wrapper object that takes as well the original object and the new parameters and serialize this wrapper object, however, if you think the data will still be serialized with the original object, then saving this with the original object, will remove any changes you have made to the xml document...

Comment: Is it not possible, to only convert the otherData (which is a XElement) to an array of bytes and then append it to the previous array.

Comment: Well yes, but not in the way you want to do it, you could create a new class that extends from MyObject, and add your own properties there and then serialize it. That you get from the one method a byte[] back is just the way you have implemented it at the moment, your export function, basically returns the raw xml (in byte array), to attach the new properties, you could theoretically deserialize your raw xml to your SecondMyObject and then fill the list of strings on the instance, and re-serialize it, if you know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Add the `XElement` returned from `GetExtraData` as `Nodes` to the original xml:

```
var doc = new XDocument(GetExtraData(new MyObject { Name = "someOtherName" }));
var byt = Export(new MyObject { Name = "nameData" });

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byt))
{
    var element = new XElement(XElement.Load(stream));
    element.Add(doc.Nodes());
}
```

And save `element`